# Show that $f(x)=-\log(1-x^2)$ with domain $\{x||x|<1\}$, is a closed function

Tags: real-analysis

> How to show that $f(x)=-\log(1-x^2)$ with domain $\{x||x|<1\}$, is a closed function?

when i construct a sequence approaching 1, my function will go to infinity.

Comment: Suggestion: reread the definition of a function being closed, and state precisely your objection to the present one being closed (since "when i construct a sequence approaching 1, my function will go to infinity" obviously does not suffice).

Comment: "When I construct a sequence approaching $1$, my function will go to infinity"... And that's a very good thing, because if $\liminf\limits_{x\to1^{-}}\log\frac{1}{1-x^2}< \alpha\in\Bbb R$ held, then $(1,\alpha)\in(\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{epi}f)\setminus\operatorname{epi}f$, which would be bad.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: the restrictions of $f$ to $[0,1)$ and to $(-1,0]$ have continuous inverse.

Hint 2: if $C\subseteq(-1,1)$ is closed, write $C=\bigl((-1,0]\cap C\bigr)\cup\bigl([0,1)\cap C\bigr)$.